# Token mismatch using react native with laravel breeze

Tags: laravel, react-native, csrf-token

I'm trying to convert a react project to react native but am having trouble with authentication. The back-end is Laravel with the Breeze kit to provide authentication. I managed to get the token from laravel-sanctum by adding a route to the api per the Laravel documentation for authenticating mobile apps.

```
Route::post('/sanctum/token', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect'],
        ]);
    }

    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
});
```

Then I hit post to this route with the login details

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.105:8000/api/sanctum/token', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        device_name: 'mobile',
    });

    const csrfToken = response.data;
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Alert.alert('Login Failed', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');
}
```

I can see the token in the response, so that part looks good.

Then I created a logout action on the client

```
const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.105:8000/logout', {});
```

I can see the X-XSRF-TOKEN and XSRF-TOKEN cookie being included in the header, but I get a token mismatch error. In case the standard 'logout' route isn't designed for mobile apps, I've also tried to create a new route for logout in the back-end.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/sanctum/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Now I get `unauthenticated`. My .env has `APP_URL=192.168.1.105:8000` and config/sanctum.php has

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1, 192.168.1.105:3000, 192.168.1.105:8000',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),
```

These two usually fix problems I have when I get 'unauthenticated' from a SPA, but they haven't helped here. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a line in the Laravel Sanctum docs, which says `When the mobile application uses the token to make an API request to your application, it should pass the token in the Authorization header as a Bearer token.`

After some digging around, I worked out that I needed to change

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;
```

to

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${csrfToken}`;
```

After making that change, laravel recognises the session.